# QT Plugin with CMake

Tags: qt, plugins, qt4, cmake

Greetings all,

I am trying to implement a QT Plugin with CMake. But this "Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2" directive stops my class from compiling. I can compile the plugin if I commented this out,but it won't work as a plugin if I do so.

QT doc says:

```
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2 ( PluginName, ClassName )
```

> The value of PluginName should
>   correspond to the TARGET specified in
>   the plugin's project file

What about in CMake case? What should be the value for 'PluginName'?

Here is my Plugin Interface :

```
#ifndef RZPLUGIN3DVIEWERFACTORY_H_
#define RZPLUGIN3DVIEWERFACTORY_H_
#include <QObject>
#include "plugin/IRzPluginFactory.h"



class RzPlugin3DViewerFactory :public QObject,public IRzPluginFactory{
      Q_OBJECT
      Q_INTERFACES(IRzPluginFactory)
private:
    QString uid;
public:
    RzPlugin3DViewerFactory();
    virtual ~RzPlugin3DViewerFactory();

    IRzPlugin* createPluginInstance();
    IRzPluginContext* createPluginContextInstance();
    QString & getPluginUID();
};

#endif /* RZPLUGIN3DVIEWERFACTORY_H_ */
```

And implementation

```
#include "RzPlugin3DViewerFactory.h"
#include "RzPlugin3DViewer.h"


RzPlugin3DViewerFactory::RzPlugin3DViewerFactory() {
    uid.append("RzPlugin3DView");

}

RzPlugin3DViewerFactory::~RzPlugin3DViewerFactory() {
    // TODO Auto-generated destructor stub
}
IRzPlugin* RzPlugin3DViewerFactory::createPluginInstance(){
    RzPlugin3DViewer *p=new RzPlugin3DViewer;
    return p;
}

IRzPluginContext* RzPlugin3DViewerFactory::createPluginContextInstance()
{
 return NULL;
}

QString & RzPlugin3DViewerFactory::getPluginUID()
{
    return uid;
}

Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(pnp_extrafilters, RzPlugin3DViewerFactory)
```

Error Message is :

> [ 12%] Building CXX object
>   CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/RzPlugin3DViewerFactory.cpp
>   .obj
>   C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\rinzo-platform\src\dlplugins\threedviewer\RzPlugin3
>   DViewerFactory.cpp:36: error: expected
>   constructor, destructor, or type
>   conversi on before '(' token make[2]:
>   *** [CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/RzPlugin3DViewerFactory.cpp.obj]
>   Error 1
>
> make[1]: ***
>   [CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/all] Error
>   2 make: *** [all] Error 2

Comment: Sorry,the error message is 

[ 12%] Building CXX object CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/RzPlugin3DViewerFactory.cpp
.obj
C:\svn\osaka3d\trunk\osaka3d\rinzo-platform\src\dlplugins\threedviewer\RzPlugin3
DViewerFactory.cpp:36: error: expected constructor, destructor, or type conversi
on before '(' token
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/RzPlugin3DViewerFactory.cpp.obj] Error 1

make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/RzDL3DView.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok , I fixed the problem by giving the project name specified in Cmake file.

PROJECT (RinzoDLPlugin3DViewer CXX C)

So,now in CPP file its

```
Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(RinzoDLPlugin3DViewer , RzPlugin3DViewerFactory)
```

and included qpluginh.h

```
#include <qplugin.h>
```

Comment: Since Qt5 Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2 is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

I think the macro should be `Q_EXPORT_PLUGIN2(pnp_rzplugin3dviewerfactory, RzPlugin3DViewerFactory)` or whatever you have listed as the **target name** in the `.pro` file. In fact, the "pnp" part stands for "Plug & Paint" which is the Qt demo program for writing plugins :)

**Edit:**
  Since I misunderstood how CMake works, this information isn't really relevant to the OP. I did do a quick search however and turned up this discussion of Qt, plugins and CMake. I hope there is some useful info there.
http://lists.trolltech.com/qt-interest/2007-05/msg00506.html

Comment: Hi Arnold,I dont use qmake and .pro files. I use CMake as my build system. I wonder how to deal this with CMake.

Comment: Oh I see. I never used CMake and was assuming that it was calling qmake.

Comment: I've edited my answer. Hopefully you will find a solution. If none are posted here, please come back and let us know if you figure it out.

Comment: hi Arnold,thats.I figured out how to fix it.I posted the anwer.
Thanks